# SASS variable for opacity

Tags: css, sass

im trying to make my overlay for the slayer slightly more controllable, so i was wondering if i can do something like:

```
.item-caption {
    background: rgba($red, $green, $blue, 0.$slider_text_background_opacity);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

the first red green and blue all works perfectly fine, when i add the opactiy tho, it doesnt do shit anymore. also leaving the 0. and putting the whole variable there does not seem to work properly.. any suggestions?

Comment: What is the reason that this must be so dynamic? Can you not set a variable which contains the whole rgba instead?

Comment: Why the 0.$slider_text_background_opacity - have you tried it with $slider_text_background_opacity set to the endvalue?

Comment: @ThomasYates so whoever uses this can decide how much opactiy he wants.. some customers are.. weird

Comment: @ThorbenLüpkes I don't work with those type of people luckily :P

Answer (score 0):

So your last variable is wrong. You can't put the value together like

```
0.$slider_text_background_opacity
```

but if you do something like

```
$slider_text_background_opacity: 0.5
```

and then put it inside the rgba-function like this:

```
background: rgba($red, $green, $blue, $slider_text_background_opacity);
```

it works.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swchkt62/

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't know what the value of user opacity is. It may be `0.2`, `20%`, `20`, `"lol"` etc.

SassMeister Demo: [link](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/0e1156ca09894b12610be09eda54b83e).

To resolve this issue you can use following code:

```
// Removes units
//  10px ->  10
//  20%  ->  20
// .2    -> .2
//  lol  ->  1
@function strip-units($value: 1) {
  @if (type-of($value) == 'number') {
    @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
  } @else {
    // Throw an error
    // @error "Error from function strip-units: parameter $value must be a number!";
    // or return default value
    @return 1;
  }
}

// Returns opacity in decimal format
//  10%  -> .1
// .1    -> .1
// -1    ->  0
//  101  ->  1
@function get-opacity($opacity: 1) {
  $opacity: strip-units($opacity);

  @if ($opacity < 0) {
    $opacity: 0;
  }

  @if ($opacity >= 100) {
    $opacity: 1;
  }

  @if (($opacity > 1) and ($opacity < 100)) {
    $opacity: $opacity / 100;
  }

  @return $opacity;
}
```